# Is there any rule for the structure of blinds in poker tournaments?

Tags: rules, tournament, blinds

I am programming an app to help dealers of home games manage the tournaments or cash games.

I realize normally blinds double his value each time blinds are raised.

Is that some kind of rule?

Should I leave the user chose the entire blinds structure or coming from the intial blinds it allways double each time blinds raise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not a rule. About 15 years ago I talked to a guy who was pushing (like trying to sale) his tournament structure. He called it "Tears". Having the blind structure, and limit times configurable would be pretty basic stuff to include in a program such as yours. I would also include a few common tournament structures for your users to pick from.